# Configure the npm to start in the background on Mac OS X

Tags: node.js, macos, apache, npm

## Description

I am on a **Mac OS X**.

Right now, I have almost 10 **Laravel/LAMP** projects locally, that I ran using vhost configured with **Apache**. The awesome part about them is even when I restart my Mac or move between networks, or even close the terminal app/tab of my projects, the Apache is still running, **all** my local sites will still be accessible.

---

## Goal

Now, I am looking to do the same things with my MEAN apps. 
How would one configure something like that ?

Let's say I have 3 MEAN apps.

Example

**App1**

- FE running on port : http://localhost:4201
- BE running on port : http://localhost:3001

**App2**

- FE running on port : http://localhost:4202
- BE running on port : http://localhost:3002

**App3**

- FE running on port : http://localhost:4203
- BE running on port : http://localhost:3003

I'm opening for anything suggestions at this moment.

Can we configure the npm to start in the background ?

---

## BE/API

[image]

## FE

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use macOS's `launchd` to run services in the background. There are a couple good GUI apps that make it easier to create launch services:

- [LaunchControl](http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/) ($10)
- [Lingon](https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) ($10) - If you go with Lingon, get Lingon X 5 from the official website instead of Lingon 3 from the Mac App Store; Lingon X 5 is more powerful because it is not limited by Apple's sandboxing.

There's also [launched.zerowidth.com](http://launched.zerowidth.com/), an interactive online tool for creating the `.plist` files that `launchd` uses.

[launchd.info](http://www.launchd.info/) is also a good resource if you want to set them up manually. [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) is available too.

---

If you are having problems with commands not working, I recommend trying these troubleshooting steps:

- Convert all your commands to use absolute paths (e.g. `npm` -> `/usr/local/bin/npm`). You can find the absolute path of a command by running `which` with the name of the command (e.g. `which npm`)
- Run your commands from within bash using `/bin/bash -c` (e.g `/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/npm start"`)

Comment: Will these suggestions start my applications in the background for me even if I restart my Mac  ?

Comment: @ihue Yes. You can make user-specific ones that only start when that user logs in, or system-level ones that start on boot.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Among the 2 which one do you have use personally ?

Comment: @ihue I've personally only created them manually; I never did enough with `launchd` to justify paying $10 for a dedicated app. I suggest using both of their trials and deciding which you like better.

Comment: Good idea ! (y) - Thanks again for this pointing me to the right the direction.

Comment: I tried this simple command, I kept getting both app to show error. Can you please help ? This is what I kept seeing : https://pasteboard.co/GXDHCta.png

Comment: Sorry, I don't know LaunchControl. Maybe it's something to do with that warning sign in the top right of the "Environment Variables" box.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160889/discussion-between-evanrelf-and-ihue).

Comment: Quit my Terminal, work great.
Reboot my Mac, also work great after a couple seconds. 

You're my hero man ! :D

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is **dockerize** your applications.

With **docker** you can run your applications in a *light weight* virtual machine known as *containers* in your computer.

This have some advantages, for example, you can *run your app with port 80* inside the virtual machine and *expose another port* to your machine. You can start or stop the container and so forth.

Go to https://www.docker.com/what-docker for more information.

Comment: Will it start my applications in the background for me even if I restart my Mac  ?

Comment: If you restart your mac docker will stop so you will need to start the container again, the good news is that you have tools like docker-compose file to save all your containers configuration, with a simple docker-compose up you can start all your machines again.

Comment: @ihue if you link this with what **evanrelf** says you can forgot about both problems the system restart and port binding.

Comment: As someone that hasn't worked much with Docker, but is generally familiar with the concept of containers - this feels like over engineering. I think you could do more with this answer to demonstrate that it isn't over engineered and actually addresses OP's core issue of being able to start up background service on start up.